# ExtJS ComboBox inside Grid

Tags: extjs

I want to have a combox inside of a grid cell, but not an EditableGrid.  What I don't like about the EditableGrid is that you have to first click on the cell to show the combobox and then you make your selection in the combobox.  I want it so that the combobox always shows in the cell.  There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this, or am I missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ext.DataView with your own XTemplate.

Its annoying but there is actually a very good reason why there is no ComboBox in each one of the rows inside a GridPanel. Imagine what would happen if your grid grew to 500 rows, wouldnt that mean 500 ComboBoxes, each with its own Store and View objects? The memory consumption on the browser would soon grow out of proportion.